# Remove leading zeros in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm displaying data from my MySQL database. I would like to remove the leading zeros in a certain fields(the `ops` and `obp` fields), **only** when the value to the left of the decimal point is a 0. If the digit(s) to the left of the decimal point is not 0, then I obviously want that displayed.

For instance,

- 0.750 becomes .750
- 1.000 stays as is

I suspect this can be done in when calling the data using django template or in the views.py. How would I do either one?

Any help on this would be greatly appreicated! Thank You.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import BattingRegStd


# Create your views here.
def batting(request):
    battingregstd2018 = BattingRegStd.objects.filter(year=2018)
    return render(request, 'playerstats/battingReg2018.html', {'battingregstd2018':battingregstd2018})
```

**models.py**

```
class BattingRegStd(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase. 
    obp = models.FloatField(db_column='OBP', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ops = models.FloatField(db_column='OPS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tb = models.IntegerField(db_column='TB', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 

{% block contents %}
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>OBP</th>
                <th>OPS</th>
                <th>TB</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for index in battingregstd2018%}
                <td>{{ index.obp}}</td>
                <td>{{ index.ops}}</td>
                <td>{{ index.tb}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that value is greater than zero.

views.py

```
def batting(request):
    battingregstd2018 = BattingRegStd.objects.filter(year=2018)

    for i in range(0, len(battingregstd2018)):
        # if need to edit value
        if battingregstd2018[i].obp is not None and battingregstd2018[i].obp < 1:
            # data edit as string
            # data type does not matter in template
            battingregstd2018[i].obp = str(battingregstd2018[i].obp)[1:]
        if battingregstd2018[i].ops is not None and battingregstd2018[i].ops < 1:
            battingregstd2018[i].ops = str(battingregstd2018[i].ops)[1:]

    return render(request, 'playerstats/battingReg2018.html', {'battingregstd2018':battingregstd2018})
```

than second attempt,
let's just fix template this time. use the original view.py

```
{% for index in battingregstd2018%}
    <td>
    {% if index.obp is None %}
    -
    {% elif index.obp < 1 %}
    .{{index.obp|slugify|slice:"1:"}}
    {% else %}
    {{index.obp}}
    {% endif %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

`.{{index.obp|slugify|slice:"1:"}}`
`|slice` can only be used in string data type.
[`|slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) converts to ASCII for use `|slice`. but decimal point is deleted.
so i added `.` to the front.

ps)
maybe, float type will store `0.750` as `0.75`. if you want to `0.750` than use it `.{{index.obp|floatformat:"3"|slugify|slice:"1:"}}`

Comment: its showing `'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`...Also, how would I have called ops in my templates?

Comment: @NickT if it worked well before (0.750, 1.000, ...), do not need to modify template. i did not see value was blank. i added condition in if statement.

Comment: Bummer. Still not working. It'll display the template without the error now but no changes. Still shows the 0 before the decimal points. Was I literally just supposed to copy and paste this in the views, change the urls.py to point to the `batting` view, and call the template as `<td>{{index.ops|default_if_none:"—"|floatformat:3}}</td>`?

Comment: @NickT i try another way.

Comment: predicty...that second one works and its the simplest! Apparently not many people know about that.  I asked on a couple forums. Lots of views, only a couple answers, and one solution!  Only thing I would add is the `|floatformat:"3"` in the else statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
def batting_avg_format(num):
    numstr = str(num)
    if numstr[0]!='0':
        return numstr
    else:
        return numstr[1:]
```

Either incorporate it as a method on your `BattingRegStd` Model and apply it, or directly do a list comprehension after you have filtered the model but before your render your HTML. The advantage of incorporating it as a model method is that you can now call it from the template, as long as the only parameter in your method is `self`.

Comment: if you add it to your model you would do it slightly different since it would be a member method.  for ods you would do something like `def batting_avg_format(self): numstr=str(self.obs)` i.e. num would be replaced by the attribute you want to format.

Comment: This way it would not need any parameters, and you could now do `{{someobj.batting_avg_format}}` from your template, where `someobj` is the name of your `BattingRegStd` object, for example `index` in your code.

Comment: Can someone look over my code to see what I'm doing wrong with Juan's approach? Click this link it'll take you to my code:  codeshare.io/aybOWo

Answer (score 0):

Examples you can confirm in a Python shell, tested with Python 3.5.3:

```
x = "0.750"
x.lstrip("0")
> '.750'

# Included because a normal floating point type won't print trailing zeroes:
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal("0.750")
x.to_eng_string().lstrip("0")
> '.750'
str(x).lstrip("0")
> '.750'
```

While you won't be able to do this in Django templates unless you've swapped out the engine for jinja2 or something else that allows parens in method calls, you can either do this in the view (possibly ugly depending on how you're pulling this data) or in a simple [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).